# How do you say "improving" or "to improve" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How do you say "improving" or " to improve" in Latin?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=sh13094) answer your question? Beyond that, we would really need more context to help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To second @SebastianKoppehel, can you give a couple of example sentences where you would want to use the verb? Context matters.

Answer (score -1):

*Melior fieri*, but context needed.